# i have 3 nested routes: class/post/comments and i don' t have idea how to code the form_for in the _form file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

If a have 2 nested routes: `post/comments`, the `form_for` is like this (in the `_form` file):

```rb
 form_for([@post, @post.comments.build])
```

But in this case I have 3 nested routes: `class/post/comments`, and I don't know how to code it in the `_form` file.

Or there is other alternative to nest 3 routes?

`config/routes.rb`

```rb
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :campus do
    resources :salas
  end
  devise_for :users
  resources :cursos do
    resources :publicacions do
      resources :comentarios
    end
  end
  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'welcome#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

```
curso_publicacion_comentarios_path  GET /cursos/:curso_id/publicacions/:publicacion_id/comentarios(.:format)    
comentarios#index

POST    /cursos/:curso_id/publicacions/:publicacion_id/comentarios(.:format)    
comentarios#create

new_curso_publicacion_comentario_path   GET /cursos/:curso_id/publicacions/:publicacion_id/comentarios/new(.:format)    
comentarios#new

edit_curso_publicacion_comentario_path  GET /cursos/:curso_id/publicacions/:publicacion_id/comentarios/:id/edit(.:format)   
comentarios#edit

curso_publicacion_comentario_path   GET /cursos/:curso_id/publicacions/:publicacion_id/comentarios/:id(.:format)    
comentarios#show

PATCH   /cursos/:curso_id/publicacions/:publicacion_id/comentarios/:id(.:format)    
comentarios#update

PUT /cursos/:curso_id/publicacions/:publicacion_id/comentarios/:id(.:format)    
comentarios#update

DELETE  /cursos/:curso_id/publicacions/:publicacion_id/comentarios/:id(.:format)    
comentarios#destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the same pattern:

```rb
form_for([@class, @post, @comment])
```

But be advised that you have some problems with you code:

- Don't use `class` to name variables, association and so, because it is used by Ruby and it will drive you into trouble.
- Do not nest routes too much. As [Rails guide says](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting), nesting more than 1 level should be avoided.
- Do not initialize objects in the form definition. Do it in the controller action or you won't be able to display validation error.

Comment: i did that and i've got an error:                                                                        NoMethodError in Comentarios#new                                               Showing /g29/app/views/comentarios/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:
undefined method `publicacion_comentarios_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007ff224188648>:0x00007ff229f2a378                       <%= simple_form_for([@curso, @publicacion, @comentario]) do |form| %>
  thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can we see your routes? Please, add the output of the following command to the original question: `rails routes -g comentario`

Comment: What if you don't use `simple_form_for`? Try `<%=form_for([@curso, @publicacion, @comentario]) do |form| %>`

Comment: Please, provide the code of the actions new/create or edit/update that are causing the error.

Comment: Finally, i nested the routes: curso-publicacion and publicacion-comentario. It is more easy, and thanks for your advice :"don't nest too much routes"!